# select the second item of an array by default in form input CakePHP 3

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In my controller I get an array ready for filling the dropdown values of an input field like this:

```
    $this->loadModel('Meetings');

    $meetings_query = $this->Meetings->find('list', ['keyField' => 'id', 'valueField' => 'date'])
            ->where( ["Meetings.date >= " =>  date('Y-m-d') ] )
            ->order( ['Meetings.date' => 'ASC'] );

    $meetings_raw = $meetings_query->toArray();

    $meetings = array();

    foreach( $meetings_raw as $key => $value ){

        if( !empty( $value ) ){
            $meetings[$key] = $value->format('Y-m-d');
        }           
    }
```

This builds an array similar to this:

```
Array ( [26] => 2016-05-25 [22] => 2016-05-28 [23] => 2016-05-30 )
```

It is then displayed as a select field in the form like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input( 'meeting_id', ['label' => 'Meeting']);
```

The first item of the array is always preselected in the dropdown. What I want to achieve is to always select the second item in the array by default.

Is that possible?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// convert to array
$a = $meetings->toArray();
// extract keys to new array
// removes the first from the array
$s = array_slice(array_keys($a),0);

echo $this->Form->input( 'meeting_id', [
 'label' => 'Meeting',
 'default' => array_shift($s) // use first value from sliced array
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Unfortunately the array_shift() did not work for some reason, so I had to use index like $s[1].

Comment: @WpDoe by me everything is working as specified. you can do as ```$d = array_shift($s)``` and ``` 'default' => $d```  : Your approach can cause errors, if there is no the index key,